# Why some applications aren't compatible? (Android sensors)

Tags: android, android-studio, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors

Lately, I have been working with java, Android Studio and Android sensors in general. What I want to ask is why some applications which are using the so-called accelerometer are incompatible with my phone. For example, I can install [**S Health**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.shealth&hl=bg) and [**Runtastic**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.runtastic.android&hl=bg) on my phone but I can't install [**Pedometer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.pedometer) (GitHub link: [**here**](https://github.com/j4velin/Pedometer)). They are all based on the same sensor that I have - accelerometer, so I can't understand why I can't run [**Pedometer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.pedometer). My phone is Lenovo Vibe K5, Android version 5.1.1 Lolipop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pedometer requires the `Step Counter` sensor, and it is not available at the [Lenovo Vibe k5] (http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Lenovo-Vibe-K5-Plus_id9976) as you can see [here](https://github.com/j4velin/Pedometer/blob/master/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L13). That why, the application is not available for your device.

Comment: S Health uses accelerometer.